# Recording video: is there an accessibility/usability/other reason for allowing video recording without audio?

Tags: accessibility, video

Imagine a chat app where you can send a text message, audio message, and video message (no screen recording - primarily used to send selfie videos). When the recording flow begins, I'm wondering if the user should be allowed to record a video with no microphone device or with their microphone muted.

I think perhaps there could be situations where for instance a user wants to use sign language but not worry about the ambient noise around them. However, I have no evidence as to if this use-case is "real" or not.

Obviously adding a "you're muted" toast for a few seconds when the recording begins would be a good way to account for erroneous video-without-audio recording attempts but I want to know if anyone has experience with a use-case where the user wanted to purposefully record a selfie video with no audio.

How would you advocate for allowing this to a PM and devs? Is it a question of accessibility or general user control and product flexibility?

Answer (score 2):

For a chat app, some videos are for showing something, not saying something (e.g., their cat doing something silly; exactly how a physical product is not working). You certainly do not want to *require* a connected microphone to record and send a video. What if the user's microphone is broken for some reason? It'll still be useful to send a video showing something happening, even if there weren't sound.

As for being able to deliberately send video without sound, I expect there are certainly situations where the ambient sound is a distraction, incongruent, or inappropriate. For example, the user wants to send a video panning over their beautiful peaceful garden, but there happens to be a road construction crew working nearby; the user wants to send a video of some baby ducks to their little nephew, but there's this drunk stranger going off with, "Look at those little f***ers!" The user is videoing the use of a product, while their 3-year-old a prattling on constantly. It probably doesn't happen much, so you are right to guard against accidentally making a video *without* sound.

More often, the user will make a recording, and an unwanted sound unexpectantly intrudes. Maybe it would be better if the user can selectively *send* the video without the sound track, rather than having to make the decision before recording it. That would cover both known and unexpected unwanted sounds.

Comment: +1.  I would just add that it'd be less error prone if the user is prompted about the audio before hitting 'send'.